# running multiple tomcat instances on Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm running Apache HTTPD on port 80, and I have 2 instances of Apache Tomcat on port 8080 and 1010. 
I deployed a war file on each tomcat:

```
project1.war on tomcat1
project2.war on tomcat2
```

The goal is being able to call project1 and project2 using just the domain, I want to avoid using the port number in the URL.

I figured out that mod_jk is the right tool to use for this purpose but I couldn't configure Apache properly to run it. I have two domains ready to use:

```
domain1.mysite.com 
domain2.mysite.com
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You could also use mod_proxy_ajp and configure that in your virtualhosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be needing some apache httpd virtual host configuration like

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName domain1.mysite.com 
   ProxyPass "/project1" "ajp://backend.example.com:8009/project1"
   ProxyPassReverse "/project1" "http://www.example.com/project1"
   # Other directives here
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domain2.mysite.com 
    ProxyPass "/project2" "ajp://backend.example.com:8009/project2"
    ProxyPassReverse "/project2" "http://www.example.com/project2"

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

composed from [Httpd VirtualHost Configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) and [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html)

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try it now. I wanted to ask you though, what does backend.example.com stand for? is it the URL that I'm supposed to type on the broswer?

Comment: That would be the url to your backend service. In case tomcat and httpd run on the same host, that would be localhost. The port in the url should point to the ajp port configured in the ajp connector in the server.xml of tomcat. ( You could also use the http connector incase mod_proxy_ajp is not installed/enabled in httpd, then point to http://<urltobackend>:<portofbacked>/<contextpath> )